# Promedio sin Pandas en Python, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

Intento calcular el promedio de edad sin Pandas de un csv Mi código va asi:

```
file_handler = open('casos_confirmados.csv') 
first = True 
for line in file_handler: 
    if not first: 
        data = line.split(',')
        if data[0] != 'NA' and data[1] != 'NA':
            edad = (int(data[3]))
            avg = 0
            for edad in file_handler:
              avg = avg + edad
              avg = avg / len(file_handler)
              print('Número de elementos:', len(file_handler))
              print('Promedio:', avg)
            

    first = False
file_handler.close()
```

Sin embargo me aparece este error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'**

Apenas voy empezando, sé que probablemente mi duda es muy básica pero no sé porque me sale ese error si lo convertí a int. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes

```
edad = (int(data[3]))
```

lo cual deja en `edad` un valor entero, pero luego reutilizas la variable para otra cosa:

```
for edad in file_handler:
```

con lo que `edad` es ahora un string.

Eso explica el error.

No ofrezco una solución pues me parece que tienes otros errores.